# Tensorflow: Extracting image and label from TFRecords file

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have a TFRecords file which contains images with their labels, name, size, etc. My goal is to extract the label and the image as a numpy array.

I do the following to load the file:

```
def extract_fn(data_record):
    features = {
        # Extract features using the keys set during creation
        "image/class/label":    tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
        "image/encoded":        tf.VarLenFeature(tf.string),
    }
    sample = tf.parse_single_example(data_record, features)
    #sample = tf.cast(sample["image/encoded"], tf.float32)
    return sample

filename = "path\train-00-of-10"
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filename)
dataset = dataset.map(extract_fn)
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
next_element = iterator.get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    while True:
        data_record = sess.run(next_element)
        print(data_record)
```

The image is saved as a string. How can I convert the image to `float32`? I tried `sample = tf.cast(sample["image/encoded"], tf.float32)` which does not work. I want `data_record` to be a list containing the image as a numpy-array and the label as a `np.int32` number. How can I do that?

Right now `data_record` looks like this:

```
{'image/encoded': SparseTensorValue(indices=array([[0]]), values=array([b'\xff\xd8\ ... 8G\xff\xd9'], dtype=object), dense_shape=array([1])), 'image/class/label': 394}
```

I have no idea how I can work with that. I would appreciate any help

**EDIT**

If I print `sample` and `sample['image/encoded']` in `extract_fn()` I get the following:

`print(sample) = 
{'image/encoded': <tensorflow.python.framework.sparse_tensor.SparseTensor object at 0x7fe41ec15978>, 'image/class/label': <tf.Tensor 'ParseSingleExample/ParseSingleExample:3' shape=() dtype=int64>}`

`print(sample['image/encoded'] = 
SparseTensor(indices=Tensor("ParseSingleExample/ParseSingleExample:0", shape=(?, 1), dtype=int64), values=Tensor("ParseSingleExample/ParseSingleExample:1", shape=(?,), dtype=string), dense_shape=Tensor("ParseSingleExample/ParseSingleExample:2", shape=(1,), dtype=int64))`

It seems that the image is a sparse tensor and `tf.image.decode_image` throws an error. What is the right way to extract the image as an `tf.float32` tensor?

Comment: hey man! what is the data_record here? What is that input?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you store images encoded as JPEG or PNG or some other format. So, when reading, you have to decode them:

```
def extract_fn(data_record):
    features = {
        # Extract features using the keys set during creation
        "image/class/label":    tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
        "image/encoded":        tf.VarLenFeature(tf.string),
    }
    sample = tf.parse_single_example(data_record, features)
    image = tf.image.decode_image(sample['image/encoded'], dtype=tf.float32) 
    label = sample['image/class/label']
    return image, label

...

with tf.Session() as sess:
    while True:
        image, label = sess.run(next_element)
        image = image.reshape(IMAGE_SHAPE)
```

**Update:**
It seems you got your data as a single cell value in a sparse Tensor. Try to convert it back to dense and inspect before and after decoding:

```
def extract_fn(data_record):
    features = {
        # Extract features using the keys set during creation
        "image/class/label":    tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
        "image/encoded":        tf.VarLenFeature(tf.string),
    }
    sample = tf.parse_single_example(data_record, features)
    label = sample['image/class/label']
    dense = tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(sample['image/encoded'])

    # Comment it if you got an error and inspect just dense:
    image = tf.image.decode_image(dense, dtype=tf.float32) 

    return dense, image, label
```

Comment: I updated my question with the error I get from `image = tf.image.decode_image(sample['image/encoded'], dtype=tf.float32) `. I also show what `sample['image/encoded']` consists of. I hope you can help me with that.

Comment: Please show us the code you used to create tfrecords.

Comment: I only have the tfrecords files. I know that it consists of images from Imagenet. That is all I know.

Comment: I still get an error. Interestingly I can extract the label. However, if I use `tf.sparse.to_dense(sample["image/encoded"])` I get the following error: `TypeError: Expected string passed to parameter 'default_value' of op 'SparseToDense', got 0 of type 'int' instead.
`

Comment: `tf.sparse.to_dense(sample["image/encoded"], default_value='')`

Answer (score 0):

If I got your point right, you simply need `numpy.fromstring`

```
img_str = (example.features.feature['image_raw'].bytes_list.value)
image = np.fromstring(img_str, dtype=np.float32)
```

Or if you need tensorflow function, you need to add `tf.decode_raw` to your parse function, I'd say it's better to separate image and label

```
def extract_fn(data_record):
    features = {
        # Extract features using the keys set during creation
        "image/class/label":    tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
        "image/encoded":        tf.VarLenFeature(tf.string),
    }
    sample = tf.parse_single_example(data_record, features)
    image = tf.decode_raw(sample['image/encoded'], tf.float32)
    label = sample['image/class/label']

    return image, label
```

Comment: I get an error if i use `tf.decode_raw()`: `TypeError: Expected string passed to parameter 'bytes' of op 'DecodeRaw', got <tensorflow.python.framework.sparse_tensor.SparseTensor object at 0x7fb19fbe1978> of type 'SparseTensor' instead.`. I also updated my question showing what `sample['image/encoded']` consists of.

Comment: @Samuel, Have you tried inspecting the file with `tf.python_io.tf_record_iterator`?