# How do I make a data set with images and labels?

Tags: tensorflow, dataset, data-science

*Beginner

I am building a neural network that determines whether a car is either model a, or model b. Based off of this prediction, I would like the network to tell me the horsepower of the car. My question is, how do I create the data set that has the image, the label of the model, and the horsepower. How do I then put it in a numpy array.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you store your image and its label (model a or b) along with its feature (horsepower) in a TFRecord, which is a file that lets you keep your database in a ready-to-use state for Tensorflow.

There is a very good tutorial on this subject exactly here: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/tfrecord

[this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54723912/tensorflow-extracting-image-and-label-from-tfrecords-file) will give you additional help in how to extract your data from the TFRecord files.